# Advice on Creating a DBMS

Tags: c++, database

I am looking at ways of creating my own DBMS from scratch in C++ (just for fun and educational purposes). I am stuck with the place to start it. Can anybody tell me how I should begin (design) this. Will postgresql code and the architecture be of any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [**SQLite**](http://www.sqlite.org/) and its doccumentation. it might be a good point to start.

Answer (score 3):

Start by reading "Transaction Processing: Concepts & Techniques" by Gray and Reuter. It goes through all the major components of a DBMS. Following the references is very interesting.

It is almost 20 years old now, but still very relevant.